# Does Wygwam 3.0.2 strip out JavaScript in Source mode?

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, javascript, wysiwyg

I have a client who uses a lot of embedded Wufoo forms in EE entries. Previously, this was no problem in Wygwam--just switch to Source mode and paste in the JavaScript from Wufoo!--but since upgrading Wygwam to 3.0.2, this client has noticed that this no longer works. Now whenever JavaScript is pasted into the Source, it seems to be getting stripped out upon submission.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is something WYGWAM used to do as well.  Here's the support thread:

https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/wygwam_deleting_javascript_tags_in_content

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was probably something XSS-related. Too bad it requires adding a regex to the config.js file. I could see that making updates trickier than they really need to be.